# GSSException: [..] Encryption type AES256CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96 is not supported/enabled

Tags: java, aes, kerberos

After setting our domain users to support AES encryption for Kerberos tokens (Windows Server 2008R2), on a web-application server side we get the following exception:

> GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level:
>   Encryption type AES256CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96 is not
>   supported/enabled)

Strangely we have Java 6 (1.6.0_27) , which means that AES should be supported, according to this document: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/jgss-features.html

Any ideas what's missing in our web-application or Java, or third parties? We are using Spring security Kerberos extension (with minimal code modifications to fit into our current Spring 2.x version and additional authentication requirements).

Comment: Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) for Unlimited Strength is now enabled by default in Java 8u161. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u161-relnotes-4021379.html#JDK-8170157

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**EDIT** (2017-05-06): upcoming JDK versions will have this included. Only a config parameter needs to be set, see [JDK-8157561](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8157561).

Follow this [link - Java SE Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), scroll down and download the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files for your specific JDK version and follow the process in this tutorial titled: [5.4.2. Kerberos and Unlimited Strength Policy](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/DIRxSRVx11/5.4.2.+Kerberos+and+Unlimited+Strength+Policy).

The basic steps are as follows:

1. locate your JDK's security directory (showing Unix below):

   ```
   $ locate 'jre/lib/security' | grep 'lib/security$'
   /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/security
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre/lib/security
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/security
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9.x86_64/jre/lib/security
   ```
2. Noting the above, we need to add the downloaded JCE .jar files to `/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/security`.
3. The JCE .zip file includes the following (showing JDK 1.7's JCE):

   ```
   $ ls -l UnlimitedJCEPolicy
   total 16
   -rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 2500 May 31  2011 local_policy.jar
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7289 May 31  2011 README.txt
   -rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 2487 May 31  2011 US_export_policy.jar
   ```
4. These are the bundled versions with the JDK (again 1.7):

   ```
   $ ls -l /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/security/*.jar
   -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2865 Mar  1  2013 /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/security/local_policy.jar
   -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2397 Mar  1  2013 /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar
   ```
5. We need to move these out of the way and replace them with the included versions in the JCE .zip file. I typically do the following:

   ```
   $ pushd /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/security/
   /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/security ~

   $ mkdir limited
   $ mv *.jar limited/

   $ cp ~/UnlimitedJCEPolicy/*.jar .
   $ ls -l *.jar
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2500 Jun 25 12:50 local_policy.jar
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2487 Jun 25 12:50 US_export_policy.jar
   ```
6. Restart anything that's making use of JDK (Tomcat, etc.).

Comment: I will try it, but to be clear: I thought it applies to JDK/JRE 5.0, not 6. Am I mistaken here?

Comment: I commented before I downloaded 'Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files' and read the readme.txt file. Thank you so much!

Comment: Have not yet tested (no access to network any more today), but I already see it should work. Any chance you might know which encryption Windows Server 2008 R2 uses by default when both AES encryption checkboxes (128bit and 256bit) are unchecked in User Account properties?

Comment: I guess when the client advertises RC4-HMAc, AES128 and AES256, the KDC will/should pick the best. You can verify that by sniffing the traffic with Wireshark.

Comment: This shouldn't be needed anymore as of Java 8u161. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u161-relnotes-4021379.html#JDK-8170157