# Encryption type AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96 is not supported/enabled

Tags: azure, hadoop, kerberos

I am trying to configure hadoop pseudo node secure cluster (to ensure proper working) in Azure using Azure Domain Service.

OS - Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 
Hadoop Version - 2.7.2

I can able to run

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

Example MapReduce job works fine

```
yarn jar %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-examples-*.jar pi 16 10000
```

But when i run,
hdfs fsck /

it gives,

```
Connecting to namenode via https://node1:50470/fsck?ugi=Kumar&path=%2F
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException:     Authentication failed, status: 403, message: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos credentails)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSck.doWork(DFSck.java:335)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSck.access$000(DFSck.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSck$1.run(DFSck.java:152)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSck$1.run(DFSck.java:149)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSck.run(DFSck.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSck.main(DFSck.java:377)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, status: 403, message: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos credentails)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticatedURL.extractToken(AuthenticatedURL.java:274)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.PseudoAuthenticator.authenticate(PseudoAuthenticator.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticator.authenticate(KerberosAuthenticator.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticatedURL.openConnection(AuthenticatedURL.java:215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.URLConnectionFactory.openConnection(URLConnectionFactory.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSck.doWork(DFSck.java:333)
    ... 10 more
```

When i access namenode web ui, it shows

```
GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Encryption type AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96 is not supported/enabled)
```

But the same configuration works fine in Local Windows Active Directory

Someone help me to resolve this error and get it work successfully.

Comment: Did you check similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956037/gssexception-encryption-type-aes256cts-mode-with-hmac-sha1-96-is-not-suppo ?

Comment: Did you check similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586132/kerberos-cloudera-krbexception-encryption-type-aes256-cts-mode-with-hmac-sh ?

Comment: Yes... No help...

Comment: Did you generate the full Kerberos debug trace as shown in https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/secrets.html ?

Comment: Let me check and update you. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have enabled kerberos logs, it seems Azure KDC don't have support for AES-256 cypto. I can access HDFS through hadoop command shell but hadoop web UI alone cannot be open and cannot access webhdfs. Hdfs fsck command also fails with "No valid credentials" found.

Comment: When you create a user account in Microsoft Active Directory UI, you have a **checkbox** for AES support; by default you only have ArcFour. So I guess you have to go back to your Azure admin console and update your own account.

Comment: BTW, does your local `krb5.conf` enable `rc4-hmac` under `permitted_enctypes` and `default_***_enctypes`? That one should be supported by Azure...

Comment: Yes it is permitted. I can able to perform hdfs operations from hadoop command shell. But webhdfs and fsck fails. Both will access hadoop rest api isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for you help. Clearly the problem is in webhdfs and hadoop web ui. By default rc4-hmac is permitted_enctypes right?

Comment: Not sure about the "defaults" used by MIT Kerberos (on Linux side) vs. Active Directory or its Azure clone (on KDC side); and they still have to negotiate so that they find a common algorithm that matches both "permitted" settings.

Comment: To enable debug traces, try `export HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG=true ; export HADOOP_OPTS="-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Dsun.security.spnego.debug=true"` for Hadoop clients.

Comment: I have enabled debug logs already as you pointed to me a link before. Let me check with "export HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG=true".